# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt x-x^2 }{1-\sqrt x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt x-x^2 }{1-\sqrt x}$$

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, since rationalizing anything doesn't quite work for me. Just looking for some help.

Comment: I don't think you ever have to rationalize if you know how to substitute and factor for limits anyways... Could be wrong...  I can't think of a case though where sub and factor wouldn't work when it is recommended you rationalize instead to find the limit.  And I guess there is the l'hospital way below too if you are allowed to use that method in beginning calculus or precal class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt x-x^2 }{1-\sqrt x}
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{x}\frac{1-\sqrt{x}^3 }{1-\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{x}\frac{(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}^2)}{1-\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{x}\frac{(1+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}^2)}{1}\\
&=3
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=\sqrt{x}$ and so $u^2=x$... The limit can be written as

$\lim_{u \rightarrow 1} \frac{u-u^4}{1-u} = \lim_{u \rightarrow 1} \frac{u(1-u^3)}{1-u} =\lim_{u \rightarrow 1} \frac{u(1-u)(1+u+u^2)}{1-u}=\lim_{u \rightarrow 1} u(1+u+u^2)=1(1+1+1^2)=1(3)=3$

Answer (score 1):

One way might be
$$\lim _{ x\to 1 } \frac { \sqrt { x } -x^{ 2 } }{ 1-\sqrt { x }  } \overset { L'hospital }{ = } \lim _{ x\to 1 } \frac { \frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  } -2x }{ -\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  }  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\to 1 } 4x\sqrt { x } -1=3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}-(1+x)^2}{1-\sqrt{1+x}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1+\frac12x\cdots-1-2x-x^2}{1-(1+\frac12x\cdots)}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{-\frac32x}{-\frac12x}$$